# Information isn't being passed to an array via Mongoose, can't work out why

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Apologies if this has been answered before, I have checked other answers and can't work it out from those.

I have a set of information that I would like placed into an array named "teamDetails". Here is the relevant /post item from server.js:

```
app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Post command received');
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.data.teamDetails[0]);
    //We need to push the variable below, 'teamDetails', as an object into an array of the same name
    var teamDetailsObj = {
    // Modified for Postman
    "teamName": req.body.data.teamDetails[0].teamName,
    "teamNameShort": req.body.data.teamDetails[0].teamNameShort,
    "teamfounded": req.body.data.teamDetails[0].teamFounded,
    "teamHome": req.body.data.teamDetails[0].teamHome
    };
    console.log(teamDetails);
    var newTeam = new Team({
        "data.added": new Date(),
        "data.entry": req.body.data.entry
    });

    newTeam.save().then((doc) => {
        console.log("This is newTeam.data: " + newTeam.data);
        console.log("This is teamDetailsObj: " + teamDetailsObj);
        newTeam.data.teamDetails.push(teamDetailsObj);
        var teamId = doc.id;
        res.render('success.hbs', {teamId});
        console.log("Team Added - " + teamId);
    }, (e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});
```

Here is my team.js model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectID = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
var Mixed = mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Team = mongoose.model('Team', {
  data: {
    entry: {
      type: String,
      default: "USER.INPUT"
    },
    added: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.Now
    },
    teamDetails: [
      {
        teamName: {
          type: String,
          trim: true,
          required: true,
          default: "First Team"
        },
        teamNameShort: {
          type: String,
          trim: true,
          uppercase: true,
          maxlength: 3,
          required: true
        },
        teamFounded: {
          type: Number,
          maxlength: 4
        },
        teamHomeCity: {
          type: String
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});

module.exports = {Team};
```

Lastly, the sample data I'm trying to inject via Postman:

```
{
    "data": {
        "entry": "Postman.Entry",
        "teamDetails": [
            {
                "teamName": "Test Teamname",
                "teamNameShort": "TTN",
                "teamFounded": "1986",
                "teamHome": "London",
                "players": [
                    {
                    "player1Name": "Test Player 1",
                    "player1Position": "Forward",
                    "player1Nationality": "GBR"
                    },
                    {
                    "player2Name": "Test Player 2",
                    "player2Position": "Defender",
                    "player2Nationality": "UKR"
                    },
                    {
                    "player3Name": "Test Player 3",
                    "player3Position": "Goaltender",
                    "player3Nationality": "IRL",
                    "captain": true
                    }
                ],
                "coachingStaff": {
                    "headCoach": "Derp McHerpson",
                    "teamManager": "Plarp McFlarplarp"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

(Disregard the players section, it's another kettle of fish)

As a result of using my code above, the resulting entry for teamDetails is just an empty array. I just can't get my code to push the teamDetailsObj into it.

Any help anyone can provide is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you add teamObjDetails AFTER saving it with `newTeam.save().then( ... )`

I'm not a lot familiar with Mongoose but I don't see how could the team details could be present if not added before saving.

Let me know if it changes something !

A. G

Comment: Using the format there, I thought that 'newTeam' didn't exist until that point, so there was nothing to push to, hence why I put it immediately after.

I did try something similar to what you suggested, where I had it as an object, being pushed into another array, which then would hopefully be saved by 'newTeam.save', but it never did.

Thanks for replying though. :)

Comment: After some search, it may be a problem with your Schema, in stead of precising teamDetails as an array of objects with teamName, teamNameShort, etc... Could you add a TeamDetails Schema and specify teamDetails as an array of TeamDetails ?

Comment: So, turns out you were right! I messed up and thought newTeam wasn't called until after, but I was wrong! Shifted it, and now I'm getting a new error, which is progress!

Error is now:  "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"[ { teamName: 'Test Teamname',\n    teamNameShort: 'TTN',\n    teamfounded: '1986',\n    teamHome: 'London' } ]\" at path \"_id\"",

Comment: Well I guess this error is caused by your schema, I wasn't able to see such definition in official documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) so it might be a good guess to create a subdocument type for your team details :)

Comment: I'll get onto that now, thanks for clearing this up for me @antoine-gautrain!